# auto login doesn't work in Safari on Mac

Tags: bug, safari, auto-login, osx

Auto login is not working in Safari browser(Version 8.0.3 (10600.3.18)) on OS X (Yosemite 10.10.2)

ie., it doesn't detect and show 'Welcome back, < user >. You've been logged in. Click here to refresh the page.'

*JS and Cookies are enabled. There are no errors in the console as well.*

*Situation: I am logged in on meta.stackexchange.com, but it doesn't show that I am logged in when I visit stackoverflow.com & other stack exchange sites*

Comment: Sure you're not in Private Mode?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Nope, positive. Not on Private Mode.

Comment: What OpenID provider are you using?

Comment: Google OpenID Login

Comment: And when you try to access gmail, you get no problems?

Comment: No problem at all. Its logged in on gmail.

Comment: Hmm.... so no idea sorry. Guess only a dev with access to the internal logs can shed more light.

Comment: Cool, shall wait. Thanks.

Comment: There are a LOT of weirdness in how cookies work in Safari when you navigate across our 2nd-level domains (from SO to SF, say.) There are some improvements in the works that will solve some, but not all of em.

Answer (score 0):

My impression is that's caused by the way `stackauth.com` authentication was implemented, which breaks with new anti-tracking security settings of the browsers, especially Safari 9 on Mac OS X.

If you enable: allow cookies from all domains, it seems to be working.

See my own ticket: [Why do Stack Exchange sites seem to always forget my login?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269658/why-do-stack-exchange-sites-seem-to-always-forget-my-login/269690#269690)