# Why do Stack Exchange sites seem to always forget my login?

Tags: bug, login, user-experience, accessibility, auto-login

It seems that all Stack Exchange sites do seem to be affected by a UX killing behaviour: it seems that every day you have to login again on each of them; they never remember your login.

For someone that is visiting these sites daily and a contributing a LOT, this is extremely annoying.

Is this so hard to implement? I don't remember when I had to re-login on Google or Facebook, still Stack Exchange keeps asking me to login all the time.

Affecting at least: stackoverflow.com, surperuser.com, serverfault.com, apple.stackexchenge.com, ask.ubuntu.com, ...

I tried logging in with all of these three variants, but it seems that there is no much difference between them: direct login, Google and Facebook.

[image]

Comment: Have you disabled/blocked cookies? Are you using private browsing? Which browser and operating system are you using? PC? Laptop? Tablet? iPhone? Android phone? **Please give us some clues!** ;)

Comment: I have none of the problems you describe, nor on my PC, nor on my laptop, nor on my phone.

Comment: OS X Safari and Chrome (all of them latest releases), both with adblocker, cookies allowed from visited domains, the usual setup of a power user. Clearly not the private mode. The issue is not new, I think it was like this for months if not always.

Comment: I think you should also allow for third-party cookies and there was a known issue with safari....

Comment: @rene damn, do I have to do this for the sake of SO? Is like opening the pandora box full of tracking agencies. Apple made a good decision with the default setting, this is not a Safari bug, is a SO bug. For the moment I made the change and tomorrow I will have the confirmation.

Comment: Sorry to burst your bubble, but *they're already tracking you.* They don't need cookies to do that, except insofar as it makes life easier for them when they want to, say, remember your login.  How else are they going to do that unless they keep some bit of information about you or your browser somewhere?

Comment: related: [one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248562/auto-login-doesnt-work-in-safari-on-mac), and the [new login post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260153/158100) that has in stage 3 this hint *(looking at you, Safari)*

Answer (score 1):

> cookies allowed from visited domains

So Stack Exchange uses several websites to log you in, and they require cookies to work correctly.

Enable cookies for the following sites and see if that changes anything:

```
stackauth.com
stackexchange.com
```

You may need to enable cookies on all the sites you visit.

Comment: Local storage is no longer required.

Comment: @AdamLear better? Are there other domains or sub domains involved?

Comment: No, really you should just need cookies allowed for whatever domain you're logging into. Ideally, you'd allow 3rd-party cookies for our other domains (this is a moot point for Safari), but if you don't all you should lose is the "log in once, log in everywhere" behaviour. You still shouldn't be getting *logged out* of a single domain. So this is interesting.

Comment: I think that the way `stackauth.com` was implemented is the cause of these login remembering failures, that's because this site is never visited by the user it means that the (new) default browser security settings will make SE forget its logins.